# Welcome the new mod?

Tags: support, bug, moderators

I was going through the Users tab when I accidentally clicked moderators and saw a fourth one. I didn't know if this was a bug or a new moderator. I know the site once had four, but I wasn't sure. Does anyone know what's going on?

[image]

The new mod hasn't been here in a while based on stats, but it appears they work for Stack Exchange. I refreshed and waited a bit, but their still there. It doesn't show up on the main Health SE either, but the site sometimes does have a lag. Either way I'll still welcome to Health SE :)

**As a update the extra mod was removed and now the list only shows the 3 true mods**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a glitch, reported at [SE employee appearing on the mod list on every per-site meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278823/se-employee-appearing-on-the-mod-list-on-every-per-site-meta)

In a nutshell: Laura had mod abilities on this site (and others), being an employee. Employees are suppressed from moderator lists. When they leave the company (as Laura did), the employee status is removed at once, but the diamond sometimes lingers.  Has diamond + not employee = appears in the list of moderators.

Comment: There are a few others, for example fitness has like 6 or 7 moderators listed on the meta. If you notice, she does not appear as a moderator in the regular site moderator list.